# iTextSharp - MVC / HTMLWorker one string to add to a paragraph

Tags: asp.net, itext

I am sending the contents of Telerik MVC Editor to the controller using Ajax as a string:
I comes out as:

```
"<strong>Hello world!</strong> <object height=\"1\" id=\"plugin0\" style=\"position:absolute;z-index:1000;\" type=\"application/x-dgnria\" width=\"1\"><param name=\"tabId\" value=\"{84594B7B-865F-4AD7-A798-294A8B0EB376}\" /></object>"
```

In the controller, I save the string to a session variable using the following:

```
        string comments = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Text);
        MySession.Current.pdfText = comments;
```

I can convert it to PDF using

```
.....
 HTMLWorker parser = new HTMLWorker(document);
.......
```

However I could not add any other paragraphes to the same page, it makes a new page.

I tried to use the following to make a new paragraph using HTMLWORK:

```
    string PDFText = MySession.Current.pdfText;
    string PDFText1 = HTMLWorker.Parse(PDFText);
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(PDFText1);
    paragraph.Add(reader);
```

I got these errors:

```
cannot convert from 'System.IO.StringReader' to 'string', and
The best overloaded method match for 'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.Parse(System.IO.TextReader)' has some invalid arguments, and
The best overloaded method match for 'iTextSharp.text.Phrase.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments
```

I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked a lot on iTextSharp and I usually follow the approach of creating a table or nested tables; if needed, with multiple rows and columns and using colspan to spread out my content on the page.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);            //Create a new table with one column
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();                //Create an empty cell
StyleSheet style = new StyleSheet();           //Declare a stylesheet
style.LoadTagStyle("h1", "color", "red");      //Create styles for your html tags which you think will be there in PDFText
ArrayList objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(PDFText),style);  //This transforms your HTML to a list of PDF compatible objects
for (int k = 0; k < objects.Count; ++k)
{
     cell.AddElement((IElement)objects[k]);     //Add these objects to cell one by one
}
table.AddCell(cell);                            //Add cell to table
document.add(table)                             //Add table to the document
```

try it out with just the paragraph once as you were trying in the question. otherwise this approach will definitely not result in a new page.

**EDIT:**

please see the updated code

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);                //Create a new table with one column
PdfPCell cellLeft = new PdfPCell();                //Create an empty cell
StyleSheet style = new StyleSheet();               //Declare a stylesheet
style.LoadTagStyle("h1", "color", "red");          //Create styles for your html tags which you think will be there in PDFText
 List<IElement> objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(PDFText),style);  //This transforms your HTML to a list of PDF compatible objects
for (int k = 0; k < objects.Count; ++k)
{
     cellLeft.AddElement((IElement)objects[k]);    //Add these objects to cell one by one
}
table.AddCell(cellLeft);                           //Add cell to table
string url = "http://localhost:1713/PDF/Images/sample.jpg"; //Image Path(can give local machine path for testing)
PdfPCell cellRight = new PdfPCell(); 
Image jpg = Image.GetInstance(new Uri(url));
cellRight.AddElement(jpg);
table.AddCell(cellRight);
document.add(table);
```

Please google for padding, margins, borders and coloring etc..

Comment: Thank you, but I am not using a table, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I know that table might sond inappropriate but its the best way to get a structured PDF which looks a lot more cleaner than adding paragraphs and phrases. Hope I get that 50 points :)

Comment: Saksham, the text should be next to an image, so how can I add the image to the table you are suggesting. Thanks